# Are there very high voltage very low amperage electromagnetic/electrostatic launchers?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, energy, acceleration, propulsion

Electromagnetic launchers (coilguns or railguns) use extremely high amperages and voltages, but I was wondering if are there very high voltage very low amperage electromagnetic/electrostatic launchers.

The only thing I could find was [electrostatic linear motors](https://youtu.be/EOgVwKbM15c), but they are very simple science demonstrators and nothing that powerful.

The only reason I find the idea interesting is because of the downsides of conventional electromagnetic launchers, they heat too much due to the insane amperage and in the case of a railgun, they self-destroy easily.
While very high voltage very low amperage currents can travel through materials with very high conductivity with almost no loss.

However, I couldn't find any information on the subject.

Comment: Even if you have insanely high voltages in order to keep the current small, the required power to send the material flying at destructive speeds, by definition, is also sufficient power to destroy whatever equipment you choose to use with. Along with the added danger that high voltages imply radioactivity. And this radioactivity would not be directed at your target, but is more likely to kill you instead.

Comment: "High voltage," "low amperage," "high conductivity." Ohm's law says you can have any two of those at the same time, but you can't have all three at the same time.

Comment: Power is volts times amps. We can do MV at MA. If you want the same power with one amp you need Terravolts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a launcher, force comes from the magnetic field. The magnetic field comes from the current. So they are designed for high current and low voltage. High current comes with high resistive heating.

There is no simple way around it. Use the strongest, lowest resistance material you can.

Superconductors might help, but they have their own problems. Keeping them cool is as hard a problem to solve as handling excess heat.